# HelpText doesnot appear on the VF Page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to add the HelpText in to the VF Page and I tried few options like below  and none of them is working for me. Added the HelpText in the `<apex:pageblockSectionItem>`

```
<apex:pageblockSectionItem helpText = "Test">
   <apex:outputPanel >
      <div class="ListLevel02">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Type 1" ></apex:outputLabel>
      </div> 
   </apex:outputPanel>
   <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!conRec.Type_I__c}" styleClass="ListLevel02"></apex:inputcheckbox>
  </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

[image]

HelpText is not enabled and cant click on them. I tried to have the HelpText added at the field

[image]

And tried using them like

```
 <apex:pageblockSectionItem helpText= "{!$ObjectType.Contact.Fields.Type_I__c.inlineHelpText}">
```

Even this has the same behaviour. Can anyone say what am I missing here

Comment: I think Visualforce attributes are case-sensitive, so try `helpText`.  Also you should use double-quotes and not single quotes for your pageBlockSectionItem example.  Also "HelpText" is not a valid attribute for `apex:outputLabel` be sure to check the [Visualforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref.htm)

Comment: @DavidCheng Sorry that was atypo I added the helpText to the `apex:pageblockSectionItem ` and I have double quotes around the String and I tried both `helpText`  as well as the `HelpText` but I just see a ? but they are disabled as shown in the image

Comment: @DavidCheng I updated the question with the updates you mentioned but still not working I just see the disabled `?`. Is there something to do with the lightning lightningStylesheets enabled on the VF

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
(SVG icon might not be visible as this is for my local machine but you can add your own image to make it work)

```
<apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;font-size:smaller;" value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.Fields.Type_I__c.label}" />
    <span class="popover" id="netNewEngagement">
        <div>
            <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle">
                <span class="slds-popover-button slds-button slds-button--icon coolGreyIcon">
                    <c:svgIcon styleClass="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small coolGreyIcon" iconLocation="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#info_alt"
                               isSLDS="true" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-popover slds-nubbin--left" role="tooltip">
                <div class="slds-popover__body slds-cell-wrap">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.Fields.Type_I__c.InlineHelpText}" escape="false" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Sorry I am not able to follow. Can you please tell me what is missing in my code why should we be creating the icons

Comment: I get error saying `Component c:svgicon does not exist`

Comment: insert any image in static resource and use it in place of  c:svgicon